# Not getting email

Tags: node.js, google-apis-explorer

I am using google sign in on my app and I am using ionic v3 and the native google plugin so the user is directed to google to sign in and allow us access.  Once the user allows access and I send the request to my backend where i use the userId sent from Google to get the users info.  I get all the info I need except for the email address.  Not sure why the users email is not showing up.  Here is my backend code:

```
        const plus = googleAPI.google.plus({
        version: 'v1',
        auth: 'My API Key' 
    });

    plus.people.get({
        userId: googleUserId,
        fields: 'displayName,emails,name'
    })
        .then((user) => {
            console.log('Google plus user: ' + JSON.stringify(user.data));
            console.log('Emails: ' + user.data.emails)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Google plus error: ' + err);
        })
```

Seems like its a permissions issue because on the app I set a iOS webClientId which is different than my API key.  If so how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out the api call was missing the accessToken as part of the get